# Can I set listen URLs in appsettings.json in ASP.net Core 2.0 Preview?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings, kestrel-http-server

I'm creating an ASP.net Core 2.0 app to run on the .net Core 2.0 runtime, both currently in their Preview versions. However, I cannot figure out how to have Kestrel use something other than the default `http://localhost:5000` listen URL.

Most documentation that I could Google talks about a `server.urls` setting, which seems to have been changed even in 1.0-preview to just be `urls`, however neither works (turning on Debug logging has Kestrel telling me that no listen endpoints are configured).

A lot of documentation also talks about a `hosting.json` and that I can't use the default appsettings.json. However, if I compare the recommended approach of loading a new config, this looks pretty much exactly like what the new [`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/f245512f6e68d65309b65528d479f32b34c67718/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L150) method does, except that it loads appsettings.json.

I currently don't understand how appsettings.json and `IConfigureOptions<T>` are related, if at all, so it's possible that my trouble stems from a lack of understanding of what [`KestrelServerOptionsSetup`](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/7ceea5323aeb78c5c5a9b0f68f1e52d65073b16f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core/Internal/KestrelServerOptionsSetup.cs) actually does.

Comment: I found that appsettings.json can be used to set urls, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696115/whats-the-point-of-hosting-json-since-appsettings-json-is-sufficient

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got it working with this

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => 
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
                .Build()
            )
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

And the hosting.json

```
{ "urls": "http://*:5005;" }
```

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood that `CreateDefaultBuilder` uses `ConfigureAppConfiguration` to load appsettings.json, which is different from `UseConfiguration`.

Comment: I'm using .NET 5 and when I create a new MVC app there isn't a hosting.json file. Should I create it or is this an outdated way of settings the URLs?

Answer (score 24):

To set listen URLs in appsettings.json, add "Kestrel" section:

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
        "Http": {
            "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Does it affect deployment on a server instance? How is the priority or order if I also set an ASPNETCORE_URLS in my service config?

Comment: Looks like ASPNETCORE_URLS (environment variable) has higher precedence than appsettings.json - See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/order-of-precedence-when-configuring-asp-net-core/

Comment: Worked for me too. Thank you. I wanted Kestrel to use a dynamic port and then I wanted to programmatically get that port. "Url": "http://*:0" did it.

Answer (score 6):

Works for me as it used to be

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseConfiguration( new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build() )
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Then

```
dotnet myapp.dll --urls "http://*:5060;"
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me. This one worked for me:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 44306, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps("mysertificate.pfx", "thecertificatePassword");
                });
            })
        .Build();
```

(Change the 44306 to a port of your own liking)

And there might be a lot of help in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621788/how-to-use-https-ssl-with-kestrel-in-asp-net-core-2-x)

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions really worked for me here in March 2024 running net8.0 and a minimal WebAPI with top-level statements.

I finally discovered code that I could add to my Program.cs that worked great:

```
var portNumber = 5270;
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    serverOptions.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, portNumber);
});
```

This set my app running on 127.0.0.1:5270.