# How to enable SSL, Windows Authentication and Anonymous Authentication through Console

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

From the project properties we could do it as follows for IIS Express
[image]

but I am using the console for a IdentityServer4 Identity provider host. 
[image]
so I must configure it from Program.cs or Startup.cs since I have no such options on project properties when using console.
[image]

Comment: AFAIK: Windows authentication is provided **by** IIS. You remove IIS you remove Windows Authentication. Kestrel is not intended to be hosted without a reverse proxy like IIS or nginx

Comment: Yes. I had read documentation about Kestrel vs HTTP.sys and I had found very useful that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621788/how-to-use-https-ssl-with-kestrel-in-asp-net-core-2-x

Comment: I hope you read the "IMPORTANT NOTE" over and over again. While your scenario is supported, it's a very bad idea

Answer (score 1):

IIS and Windows authentication is not applicable when you host your service with the console app. I am using the below code enable HTTPS for my identity server

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel(options => 
                {
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any,44333, listenOptions =>
                    {
                      listenOptions.UseHttps("Path to SSL certificate","SSL Cert Password");
                        }

                    });
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using .NET Core.

.NET Core is hosted in Kestrel instead of the normal IIS and does not support windows authentication. Although you can use [HTTP.sys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which is a web server implementation in .NET Core and **does** support windows authentication.

The below code configures the app's web host to use HTTP.sys with Windows authentication.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) => 
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseHttpSys(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.Schemes = 
                    AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
            })
            .Build();
}
```

the article explaining this code is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x])

Comment: ".NET Core is hosted in Kestrel instead of the normal IIS and does not support windows authentication" this is completely wrong. Kestrel supports IIS and it's the default integration in new projects

Comment: Since HTTP.sys only works on windows and I will porting to docker the application behind a web server proxy. I will continue using Kestrel. Thanks anyway for your reply

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto please check here for more information on Kestrel: [Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

> Kestrel is a cross-platform web server for ASP.NET Core based on libuv, a cross-platform asynchronous I/O library. Kestrel is the web server that's included by default in ASP.NET Core project templates.

Kestrel is the web server .NET Core is hosted in. IIS is one of many possiblities to use as a reverse proxy to get the traffic to the Kestrel web server.

-edit for user tagging