# Using Kestrel, Https with during development mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

Seems setting Https is not enough, How do I configure Kestrel with development certificate?

```
  return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:8001", "https://localhost:8002")
                .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
                .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
                .Build();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46621789/1431250

Do I need to create a development certificate and install in the machine and put the name, or can attaching .pfx certificate be relaxed in development mode?

Comment: Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1#endpoint-configuration