# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0] Unable to start Kestrel

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

when I run my image docker he give me this error

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: HTTPS endpoints can only be configured using KestrelServerOptions.Listen().
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAddressAsync(String address, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, List`1 listenOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: HTTPS endpoints can only be configured using KestrelServerOptions.Listen().
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAddressAsync(String address, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, List`1 listenOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at Btorport.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in /App/Btorport.Web/Program.cs:line 13
```

I think the problem with the certificate so I removed and I added from new by exec this command in my project -->

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

But I am not using kestrul in my project I don't know why give me this error??

& this my BuildWebHost Methode

```
 return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("http://*:5050;https://*:5050")
                  .UseStartup<Startup>()
                  .Build();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621788/how-to-use-https-ssl-with-kestrel-in-asp-net-core-2-x

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying that it should use port 5050 for both http and https. That's not possible. It needs to be different ports.

For instance

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("http://*:5050;https://*:5051")
                  .UseStartup<Startup>()
                  .Build();
```