# What's the point of hosting.json since appsettings.json is sufficient

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

In .NET Core 2 Web API app, I could override configuration `urls` using `appsettings.json`, but in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x#overriding-configuration) they introduced extra file "hosting.json", Why? What's the point of adding complexity?

Below code is fully working using `appsettings.json`:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) //see Side note below
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
}
```

appsettings.json content:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "urls": "http://*:5005/"
}
```

Side note:
Commenting `.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` will keep VS 2017 debug mode operational (means apply `launchSettings.json`, and auto launch url) otherwise it won't. I guess its related to the [CreateDefaultBuilder](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L152) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it’s just a convention used to separate host and application configuration to follow SRP (single responsibility principle).
You can keep them in the same file and , if you want, separate by comments

Answer (score -1):

I think, **hosting.json** is a configuration file used specifically for asp.net core application hosting. (if you know more about hosting)

WebHostBuilder directly maps its keys with the hosting.json file and it doesn't have the capability to load the **config section** as we do in normal configuration settings.

According to link attached in your post

> Use Configuration to configure the host. In the following example,
>   host configuration is optionally specified in a hosting.json file. Any
>   configuration loaded from the hosting.json file may be overridden by
>   command-line arguments.

If only we explicitly us **hosting.json** then the WebHostBuilder configurations can be modified using dotnet command.

for example

dotnet run --urls "http://*:8080"

this will override the urls from hostings.json file.

Hopefully, this may give some idea.

> PC: **hosting.json** can be renamed like **myappsettings.json** it can
>   have configuration and Web Host Builder configuration.

Comment: To override  hosting.json or any [name].json urls from command line, its done by .AddCommandLine(args), nothing special about hosting.json in that regards.

Comment: I think to override hosting.json. that's what the documentation says. Also, it makes sense to have hosting.json which has specific host config other like any other jargons like db config or logging or another config details.

Comment: It's very common design to have single config file per app. when user plan to deploy an app, jumping between different config files to tweak or verify config params isn't nice.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh yes it is and I do agree.