# Asp.Net Core Web API app: how to change listening address?

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel

I write simple Asp.Net Core WebAPI 2.0 application, it works on my local machine.
But i want to deploy it to server.
So, i do it.

My system:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.
Asp.Net WebAPI 2.0 (and dotnet version 2.1.105)
```

But, when app starts it writes:

```
Now listening on:http://localhost:53115
```

When i try to get values from it:

```
  http://id_address:53115/api/values
```

And i can not get response.
In Postman:

```
 Could not get any response
 There was an error connecting to 
 http://id_address:53115/api/values.
 Why this might have happened:
 The server couldn't send a response:
 Ensure that the backend is working properly
 Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
 Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
 Proxy configured incorrectly
 Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
 Request timeout:
 Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

What i should do? Can you tell me how to fix that?

I do not know where to start looking for.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are hosting it using `Kestrel` then the default port is 5000

Comment: @SimplyGed, i try 5000, but it is the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using .NETCore 2.1 prev, so I haven't been able to test it myself but if I believe that https://www.billbogaiv.com/posts/setting-aspnet-host-address-in-net-core-2, adding `.UseUrls(urls: "http://*:5000")` might be instructing Kestrel to listen to port 5000 and not only on localhost, so it should work also on a remote server.

Other possible solution, `UseKestrel(..)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x using `IPAddress.Any` instead of `Loopback`.

Answer (score 10):

This is configured by [Server urls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#server-urls) host configuration

> Indicates the IP addresses or host addresses with ports and protocols that the server should listen on for requests.
>   **Key**: urls
>   **Type**: string
>   **Default**: http://localhost:5000
>   **Set using**: UseUrls
>   Environment variable: ASPNETCORE_URLS
>
> Set to a semicolon-separated (;) list of URL prefixes to which the server should respond.

---

It is also possible to set URL using command line arguments. For example:

> dotnet run --urls=http://0.0.0.0:5001

but this doesn't work out of the box for old versions of ASP.NET Core ([depends on whether this fix applied to used version or not](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/issues/221)).

A workaround for old versions based on fact that you always can set host settings directly via `.UseConfiguration` method:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build();

return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseConfiguration(config)
```

Note, the same idea may be used to read setting value from any other configuration source, like [configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118610) for example.

Comment: I tried all kinds of variation on the `--urls` option, but I couldn't get anything to work

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, it worked for me.

set ASPNETCORE_SERVER.URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000/