# Unable to change listening port via environment variables with ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-2.0

In my ASP.NET Core 2.0 application my web-host ist built like this:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseNLog()
        .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
        .Build();
```

I tried to override the listenting port by setting the environment variable:

```
SET ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5001
```

But on startup my application still says

```
Now listening on: http://[::]:5000
```

I also tried to explicitly include environment variables as configuration source like this:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseNLog()
        .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
        .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().Build())
        .Build();
```

But it doesn't work either.

So how can I make the listening port configurable via environment variables (and still provide a hardcoded default)?

Comment: Then answer from Set here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50099519/6827240, with the command line argument might be working in your case, no?