# Changing hostname and port hosting .net core DLL on Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, centos, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel

I'm trying to host my first service on a CentOS Linux VM.

My launchSettings.json looks like this :

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64707",
      "sslPort": 44323
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/test/get",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Release"
      }
    },
    "TestService": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/test/get",
      "applicationUrl": "https://centos-vm:1234",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Release"
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Note the hostname and port.

I publish the service with the following settings : 
[image]

I then FTP the published files to my VM, and start up the service with this :

```
dotnet mytestservice.dll
```

The service starts running, and inflating all the DLL's. However, my problem comes with this prompt :

> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

How do I specify the hostname and port, and change the connection to be secure (https)?

Comment: What kind of service is this? ASP.NET?

Comment: @MindSwipe. Apologies, its a web api service. Adding the tag now.

Comment: what is your `appsettings.json`?

Comment: @Misiakw, updated question

Comment: try adding `"BaseUrl": "{your desited url}"` to appsettings

Comment: i found the same problem with verified solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097268/asp-net-core-web-api-app-how-to-change-listening-address. If it will help - please remember to mark answer from that solution as usefull

Comment: @Misiakw, thanks. This is indeed a duplicate. That post, as well as the accepted answer below, lead me to the correct answer.

Comment: try this -> set ASPNETCORE_SERVER.URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Program.cs you have the method `CreateHostBuilder`, you'll need to adjust this method. By default it looks something like this:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel();
                    webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                });
```

Here you can customize the web host. In your case to change the URL used you can use `webBuilder.UseUrls("Url 1", "Url 2"...)`