# AspNetCore Httpsys configure useURLS from webapi Appsettings file

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I am building a AspNetCore webapi application for internal corporate use and I need to enable Windows Authentication.

So I am creating a httpsys server to listen at a specific endpoint:

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .UseHttpSys(options =>
                {
                    options.Authentication.Schemes =
                            AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                    options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:16000");
                }).UseUrls("http://localhost:16000");
```

so while this obviously works fine, I want to be able to configure it in the config file.

Earlier in the project I was using Kestrel, so I just added these settings to the   application config:

```
"Kestrel": {
   "EndPoints": {
     "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
       "Url": "https://*:16000",
        "Certificate": {
          "Subject": "localhost",
          "Store": "My",
          "Location": "LocalMachine",
          "AllowInvalid": "true"
        }
    } ...
```

Now I understand perfectly that HttpSYS can be configured by the registry etc, so I am not interested in those kinds of responses.

My Specific question is:  For a NetCoreApi web api application, is it possible to use the IConfiguration inside the (static) CreateWebHostBuilder method?

I am injecting the IConfiguration into the startup class, but it appears the limitation is in the framework preventing access to it in the CreateWebHostBuilder method.  Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a NetCoreApi web api application, is it possible to use the
>   IConfiguration inside the (static) CreateWebHostBuilder method?

Yes, you will be able to access it inside `ConfigureServices`, which is enough to make your configurations. The overloaded of `UseHttpSys` actually does the exact same thing.

So basically you just have to configure your `HttpSysOptions`.

For netcoreapp2.1 :

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseHttpSys()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            // Option 1. Set options manually.
            services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Use context.Configuration to access your config.
                var url = context.Configuration.GetSection("MySection")["Url"];
                options.UrlPrefixes.Add(url);
            });

            // Option 2. Build options from settings.
            services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(context.Configuration.GetSection("WebSys"));
        });
```

For netcoreapp3.1:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    // Option 1. Set options manually.
                    services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(options =>
                    {
                        // Use context.Configuration to access your config.
                        var url = context.Configuration.GetSection("MySection")["Url"];
                        options.UrlPrefixes.Add(url);
                    });

                    // Option 2. Build options from settings.
                    services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(context.Configuration.GetSection("HttpSys"));
                });
                webBuilder.UseHttpSys(options =>
                {
                    // Verify that your options is correct here.
                });
            });
```

In case you want to use option 2, your `appsettings.json` should look something like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "HttpSys": {
    "AllowSynchronousIO": false,
    "RequestQueueLimit": 2,
    "MaxAccepts": 3
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Note that the property `UrlPrefixes` in `HttpSysOptions` is a rather complex object, so I'm not sure if you will be able to serialize it correctly from `appsettings`. However, you can simply set the field as `urls` in your config, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118610/4949005). Then `HttpSys` will pick it up as long as your `Configuration` is correct.

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "urls": "http://*:5005;",
  "HttpSys": {
    "AllowSynchronousIO": false,
    "RequestQueueLimit": 2,
    "MaxAccepts": 3
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
 }
```