# Setting url of application from appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hello i  need to use the `appsettings` (or another jsonfile) before the `Startup` class is initialized , specifically in the `CreateWebHostBuilder` that is called in `Program.Main` . I want to set the `UseUrls(url)` for the application.
I want to somehow reuse the same resource when using the `IConfiguration` in the `Startup` class.

How can achieve this ?

```
public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {

            WebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder();
            builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            //load the Port and Host from appsettings
            var url =$"http://{appsettings.host}:{appsettings.port}/";
            Debug.WriteLine(url);
            builder.UseKestrel().UseUrls(url);
            return builder;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set listen URLs in appsettings.json in ASP.net Core 2.0 Preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117840/can-i-set-listen-urls-in-appsettings-json-in-asp-net-core-2-0-preview)

Comment: Your question is answered on this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738692/read-appsettings-json-in-main-program-cs

Comment: I do not understand : so you create a `Configuration in the main` method but how do you bind it to the application so that you can later refer it in the `Startup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there're two great answers by [@Ígor Krug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118610/10091607) and @[Tseng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41738816/10091607) (and I've voted up for the two answers).  The explanation below is just to answer the OP's question in the comment. (I tried to file a comment , but it's awful to paste so much words in a comment)

---

> I do not understand : so you create a Configuration in the main method but how do you bind it to the application so that you can later refer it in the Startup?

As you know, the `Startup` doesn't care about how the `Configuration` is constructed.  If you want to share the configuration with host builder and application (including `Startup`), there're two ways to do that.

1. As @[Tseng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41738816/10091607) does, simply **invoke `.UseConfiguration(config)`**. **The `.UseConfiguration` method will specify a configuration for host builder**, and also **this configuration will be reused by application**. As for your original question, add an `urls:"https://your.host.name:port"` setting in your `appsettings.json`:

   ```
   {
       "urls": "http://localhost:8809",
        ...
   }
   ```

   and simply copy [Tseng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738692/read-appsettings-json-in-main-program-cs) with a little change:

   ```
   WebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder();
   builder.UseStartup<Startup>();

   var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
       // ...
       .Build();

   return builder
        // the `config` will be reused by application (including Startup)
       .UseConfiguration(config)      
       .UseKestrel();
   ```
2. Or if you would like to add a separate configuration for your application (including `Startup`), you could **invoke `.ConfigureAppConfiguration(c=>{ /*...*/ })`** . **This part of configuration will not be shared with host builder** :

   ```
   return builder
       // .UseConfiguration(config) 
       .UseUrls(config["urls"])
       .UseKestrel()
       .ConfigureAppConfiguration(c =>{
           c.AddConfiguration(config);
       })
   ```