# How to define appsetting properties when publishing an asp net core 3.1 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, release, configuration-files, execute

I have a webapi app made using rider and asp net core 3.1

Under the Properties folder of my project I have a launchSettings.json that seems the place to add all the information to make my app launch the way I like. Here is my launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false
  },
  "profiles": {
    "AuthWebApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5137"
    }
  }
}
```

My problem comes when I want to publish my app. Everything goes well but when I execute my dll with donet, it starts on port 5000 instead of the one I configured in launchSettings.json (5137). I guess this is because the configuration I defined takes effect only in debug. But I'm not sure.

I know I could use the url param when running my binary to make it listen on the port I want but I prefer to have all configuration in the launchsettings.json.

Is this possible? How do you handle your launch settings for a publisher app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`launchSettings.json` is used [only for development environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#development-and-launchsettingsjson):

> The launchSettings.json file:
>
> - Is only used on the local development machine.
> - Is not deployed.
> - contains profile settings.

To set up production/staging environment you can use environment variables and/or configuration files.

Comment: Thanks, could you expand a bit on what are these configuration files? Are files specific to asp net core?

Comment: @Notbad [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) you can read about configuration is ASP Core.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I knew this files, just wanted to make sure we were talking about the same ones ;)

Comment: @Notbad Also for urls [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117840/can-i-set-listen-urls-in-appsettings-json-in-asp-net-core-2-0-preview) should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an answer for your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365277/how-to-specify-the-port-an-asp-net-core-application-is-hosted-on)

You can use following command:

```
dotnet run --urls=http://localhost:5001/
```